# How to get gender and birthday from Google OAuth

Tags: google-oauth, oauth2-playground

I am trying to retrieve gender and birthday from Google accounts. I am trying in Google Playground (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) by doing the following:

I authorize all Google OAuth2 API V2 scopes (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile).
Then I generate the access token and finally I make a request to https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me.

The information I get is: *family_name*, *name*, *picture*, *locale*, *email*,  *given_name*, *id* and *verified_email*. I tried many things but I cannot get gender or birthday.

NOTE: The account I am using has both gender and birthday marked as public (checked in https://aboutme.google.com)

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is what you want, how about using ``https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me`` as the endpoint? This is [People: get of Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get). For this API, you can use the 4 scopes that you have already used. The response includes ``birthday`` and ``gender``. If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Yes, it gives me some more information about the user but I still don't get gender and birthday. Thanks anyways

Comment: I'm really sorry I couldn't help.